# Pasting as object names

Tags: r

I am trying to use paste0 with merge, so that I can merge a bunch of stuff in a loop. However, I'm having trouble with calling specific columns from data.frames

To illustrate, I'll use head

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
head(df)
    x  y
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6

head(get("df"))
    x  y
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6    

head(df$x)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

head(get("df$x"))
Error in get("df$x") : object 'df$x' not found
```

Is there a way to get a specific column?

Comment: There are many duplicates of this question: `get(df)[['x']]`

Comment: It also seems like there are better ways to do what you are trying to do without using `get`. In particular the title of your question is not aligned with the final statement. We might be able to help you better if you give us a proper example of what you mean by "trying to use paste0 with merge, so that I can merge a bunch of stuff in a loop"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get` looks for objects defined in an environment. If you do not specify the environment, it defaults to your global workspace.

You need to coerce `df` into an environment using `as.environment`, and then call get using this environment, e.g.:

```
get("x", as.enviroment(get("df")))
```